# VBA Hyperlink to Module does nothing when clicked

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am currently trying to put a hyperlink in one overarching tab that would trigger an autofilter in another tab once clicked. I've put in what i believe to be the correct macro for the hyperlink but when clicked nothing happens. I even tried it on a new Excel document and the code works fine. Is there something I could update in my document to allow hyperlinks or is my code incorrect.

Thanks!

In-Sheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Hyperlink(ByVal Target As hyperlink)
If Target.Range.Address = "$F$5" Then
Call hyperlink2
End If
End Sub
```

Reference Code:

```
Sub hyperlink2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("NJ Reporting Template").Activate
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
Range("Z6").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$N$6:$Z$150").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="Yes"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: change trust center settings for code to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you stepped through? Is the hyperlink firing at all?

Comment: And isn't the sub supposed to be `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` not just `Worksheet_Hyperlink`

Comment: You're a genius!!!! It works with Worksheet_FollowHyperLink, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks everyone!